# how to make drivers turn on and off at random

Tags: transforms, drivers, visibility

im making a scene where the visibility of these scribbles are controlled by the rotation of a controller object. its usable but i want the drivers to select which scribble is visible at random instead of there being an order. is this possible with drivers?

[image]

[blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14njY8Aqu6AGBdH21idkhK-B-YOrquUUC/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

delete all your drivers.

Insert this into text file:

```
import bpy
import random

objects = ["NurbsPath", "NurbsPath.001", "NurbsPath.002", "NurbsPath.003"]

def showObject(obj, TrueOrFalse):
    obj.hide_render = TrueOrFalse
    obj.hide_viewport = TrueOrFalse
    

def randomVal():
    
    for eachObj in objects:
        showObject(bpy.data.objects[eachObj], True)
        
    
    val = random.randint(0,3)
    
    showObject(bpy.data.objects[objects[val]], False)
    
    print("----")
    print("val=",val)
    print(bpy.data.objects[val].name)
    
    return val != 0




# Add functions defined in this script into the drivers namespace.
bpy.app.driver_namespace["randomVal"] = randomVal
```

Run it once.

Then on Nurbspath visibility insert this as driver:

[image]

Comment: this works but how could i use an object to control what shows? (basically like using the x rotation of the changer object to make a random one of the paths appear and then being able to rotate it further for another random path to show) in simpler terms i need them to constantly being shown and hidden at random

Comment: normally this should change on every frame....doesn't it?

Comment: no it does not. here is what ive done so far https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IEpdTXvruECkI9IjX6Avf6uBMJ0xs5MQ/view?usp=sharing